# Combine 2 objects from 2 arrays in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm creating a deck of cards (an array of card objects) by combining an array of suit objects, and an array of card objects, using javascript.

I'm using a forEach loop to loop through the suits, and nested is a map loop for the cards.

The console.log is returning the correct object to push to the new array, however the .push() is only appending a combined object using the last suit and the last card.

Where am I going wrong with this?

I have tried multiple different loops and methods to append to a new array without luck.
Console.log() returns the correct value, but I am unable to push the correct combined objects to a new array.

```js
  // Deck of Cards
var suits = [
  { suit: "clubs", color: "black" },
  { suit: "spades", color: "black" },
  { suit: "hearts", color: "red" },
  { suit: "diamonds", color: "red" }
];

var family = [
  { name: "2", value: 2 },
  { name: "3", value: 3 },
  { name: "4", value: 4 },
  { name: "5", value: 5 },
  { name: "6", value: 6 },
  { name: "7", value: 7 },
  { name: "8", value: 8 },
  { name: "9", value: 9 },
  { name: "10", value: 10 },
  { name: "J", value: 10 },
  { name: "Q", value: 10 },
  { name: "K", value: 10 },
  { name: "A", value: 1 },
];

var deck = new Array();

suits.forEach(function (x) {
  var arr = family.map((y) => {
    var obj = Object.assign(x, y);
    console.log(obj);
    deck.push(obj);
    return obj;
  });
  
  console.log(arr);
});

console.log(deck);
```

Comment: Some notes: 1. You don't need to assign the `arr` variable since it isn't being used anywhere (other than the console.log statement later), 2. You should use `.forEach` instead of `.map` for the inner loop since you're pushing the desired object onto the `deck`, 3. With `.map` updated to `.forEach`, you should remove the return value from it

Comment: @stevendesu Your 100% right - I was using .map and assigning it to a new array for  troubleshooting. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try `Object.assign({}, x, y)` instead of `Object.assign(x, y)`. Currently you're manipulating the object that is x, by adding all properties of y to it.

```js
// Deck of Cards
var suits = [
    {suit: "clubs",color: "black"},
    {suit: "spades",color: "black"},
    {suit: "hearts",color: "red"},
    {suit: "diamonds",color: "red"}    
];

var family = [
    {name: "2",value: 2},
    {name: "3",value: 3},
    {name: "4",value: 4},
    {name: "5",value: 5},
    {name: "6",value: 6},
    {name: "7",value: 7},
    {name: "8",value: 8},
    {name: "9",value: 9},
    {name: "10",value: 10},
    {name: "J",value: 10},
    {name: "Q",value: 10},
    {name: "K",value: 10},
    {name: "A",value: 1},
];

var deck = new Array();

suits.forEach(function(x){

    var arr = family.map( (y) => {
        var obj = Object.assign({}, x, y); 
        deck.push(obj);
        return obj; 
    });

});

console.log(deck);
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought given that the target object is returned, it wouldn't make a difference if it was a new or existing object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign(x,y)` will put the values of `y` onto `x`.  You want to leave `x` alone, so store your properties in a new Object using `Object.assign({}, x,y)`.  Consider the demo below:

```js
var suits = [
    {suit: "clubs",color: "black"},
    {suit: "spades",color: "black"},
    {suit: "hearts",color: "red"},
    {suit: "diamonds",color: "red"}    
];

var family = [
    {name: "2",value: 2},
    {name: "3",value: 3},
    {name: "4",value: 4},
    {name: "5",value: 5},
    {name: "6",value: 6},
    {name: "7",value: 7},
    {name: "8",value: 8},
    {name: "9",value: 9},
    {name: "10",value: 10},
    {name: "J",value: 10},
    {name: "Q",value: 10},
    {name: "K",value: 10},
    {name: "A",value: 1},
];

const tmp = suits.reduce((acc, s) => {
  return acc.concat(family.map(f => {
    return Object.assign({}, f, s);
  }));
}, []);

const pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tmp, null, 4);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Comment: Why the `...` operator? `.concat()` can accept an array argument, you don't need to spread it

Comment: @stevendesu You're right, I thought it would concat the Array as an Array and not flatten it.

Comment: `flatmap` and object spread make this even easier: `const deck = suits.flatMap(s => family.map(f => ({...s, ...f})))`

Comment: @ScottSauyet True, but `flatmap` doesn't have any IE support.  It would be a much cleaner solution though.

Comment: Yes, always the problem child, that browser!

Answer (score 1):

If [you can use `flatmap`](https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap), then it can be made significantly simpler:

```js
const suits = [{ suit: "clubs", color: "black" }, { suit: "spades", color: "black" }, { suit: "hearts", color: "red" }, { suit: "diamonds", color: "red" }]
const family = [{ name: "2", value: 2 }, { name: "3", value: 3 }, { name: "4", value: 4 }, { name: "5", value: 5 }, { name: "6", value: 6 }, { name: "7", value: 7 }, { name: "8", value: 8 }, { name: "9", value: 9 }, { name: "10", value: 10 }, { name: "J", value: 10 }, { name: "Q", value: 10 }, { name: "K", value: 10 }, { name: "A", value: 1 }]

const deck = suits.flatMap(s => family.map(f => ({...s, ...f})))

console.log(deck)
```

A side note, there seems to be a strong convention (presumably from Bridge) of ordering the suits clubs/diamonds/hearts/spades.  In English that's easy to remember since they're alphabetic.)

Comment: Great alternative, thanks for the heads up about the ordering of suits too!